# Java Date conversion

Tags: java

I want to convert this incoming date "962409600000" to date.I first tried to convert it to datetime format "2000-07-01T05:45:00.000+05:45" and then convert it to 2000-07-01.But I am successful to convert to datetime format.Please help me how ca I do that.

Thanks

Comment: What does that number mean? What have you tried? What was the result? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask Please read this.

Comment: Consider adding more information (code snippets with what you tried) and also try to be more clear in explanations.

Comment: The number means a date in datetime format.I have to change it in date only format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parse the String to Long format

```
 Long inComingDate = Long.parseLong("962409600000");//parse the string to long
```

Construct the Date object and format it using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
  Date date = new Date(inComingDate); //Convert the java.util.Date
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");  //convert it format you desire
  String dateInString = format.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to get it as a `Date`, just use:

```
Date date = new Date(962409600000L);
```

If you want that as a *string* representation, use:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String text = format.format(date);
```

Note the part setting the time zone to UTC - the value you've given is midnight UTC on July 1st. If you apply the default time zone, you'll end up with the day before anywhere which is behind UTC in summer time.